# Doubts on solving an initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is : $y(\ln y)'= \frac{2t}{y}$ with  $y(0)=0$. How to obtain $y'$ ?

Comment: People on MSE like questions when the asker explains things a bit more. Where did you come across this problem? Why do you care about the answer? You say you're having a hard time removing $y'$; what attempts did you make in that direction?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I used separation to get d(ln(y) y^2)=2t dt but what confuses me about that is not being able to integrate ln(y) y^2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on Ross Millikans answer

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \ln y \bigg) &= \frac{1}{y} \cdot y' \\
\implies y\frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \ln y \bigg) &= y' \\
&= \frac{2t}{y} \\
\implies y' - \frac{2t}{y} &= 0
\end{align}$$

Now you can use an integrating factor or note that

$$yy' = \frac{d}{dt} \bigg( \frac{1}{2} y^{2} \bigg)$$

and then separate and integrate.

Comment: Ooooh!! Now it all makes sense thank you.

Comment: Would someone care to explain why they downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Use the chain rule.  What is $\frac d{dt} (\ln(y))$?

Comment: Makes sense. So then I would use separation to get d(y^2 ln(y))=2t dt? I'm confused because leaving y^2 ln(y) without integrating doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

$y(\ln y)'=y(\dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{dy}{dt})=\dfrac{dy}{dt}.$

So the problem is $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{2t}{y}\implies ydy=2t dt$

So, $\dfrac{y^2}{2}=t^2+C,$ thus with the initial condition $y(0)=0$, we get $C=0$

ie, $y^2=2t^2\implies y=\pm \sqrt2t \square$